# Pound as alternative to mod_proxy

Tags: pound

I want to switch from a apache ReverseProxy to pound.

My problem is: 
There are rules in my proxy.conf like: 
ProxyPass /lalelu http://internale/NOT_Lalelu

Now in pound I couldn´t figure out how to "map" this. 
I can only:

`Service 

URL "/lalelu" 

Backend 

    Adress internal

    Port

  End 

End`

Am I wright, or is there a way to map a directory to the root or to another directory?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think pound is capable of that, unless there's new (since 2-3 years) features that does this. The config above would send a request with URI that starts with /lalelu to a certain backend(s), without rewriting the URI.

Answer (score 1):

Pound is really fast, stable, and simple. I found that BackEnd (proxy) and Redirect was all we needed. Pound's Redirect clause takes regular expressions.

The HTTP redirects are not the same as ProxyPass (because they do not hide the mapping from the user) but it will probably work for you too.

For your example it would be:

```
Service
  URL "^/lalelu"
  http://internale/NOT_Lalelu 
End

Service
  URL "/NOT_Lalelu"
  Backend
    Adress internal
    Port
  End
End
```

Here are some other examples that we use:

```
Service
  HeadRequire "^Host: fmspbm\.ucr\.edu$"
  URL "^/?$"
  Redirect    "http://fmspbm.ucr.edu/binplone"
End
```

or

```
Service
  URL "^/(~|%7E)userxyz"
  HeadRequire "^Host: biocluster\.ucr\.edu$"
  Redirect    "http://biocluster.ucr.edu/~userx"
End
```

Comment: this sounds good! The "^" is the regex Start-String ... right?

Comment: @Matthias, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of using Apache is that you get excellent URL (and content) rewriting capabilities.

If you're moving away from `mod_proxy` for performance reasons, you may want to look at [Varnish](http://varnish-cache.org), although Varnish by itself doesn't do SSL (a typical solution uses stunnel, Pound, or Apache to provide the SSL services).  Varnish can perform arbitrary regular-expression based rewriting on URLs (and also has load-balancing features).